# How can I aggregate the messages I split splitter in spring integration?

Tags: spring-integration

Using the splitter in Spring Integration, I split rows of data selected from a table in database. 
After Each message finish the process, I want to aggregate every message to one message like the old one. How can I do? I don't know how many the splitter splits message. All I know is just the correlation id in the header of the split message. Even if I aggregate the messages, I can not make the release strategy.

How can I solve this?

And Is there any way to insert multi-rows of data using jdbc-outbound-gateway or jdbc-outbound-channel-adaptor at one time without using splitter for inserting each one row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, if you use the default splitter strategy, it will populate whole `SequenceDetails` including `sequenceSize`. In the end aggregator with default strategy can correlate message and release them using those `SequenceDetails`.

Of course, if you use the custom splitting logic you should provide those headers manually. If you know the size, of course - `MessageBuilder#pushSequenceDetails` for each splitted message.

In this part we need to know more info about you case. Some example of your code would be great too.

Re. batch insert: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3364. As you see we haven't implemented it yet. But it enough simple to workaround it with direct `JdbcTemplate` usage from `<outbound-channel-adapter>`

Comment: I can't know how to get the SequenceDetails in the aggregator, especially in the release streategy. Can you make simple sample for me?